# What happens to a resolution after an unfavorable recommendation in the US Congress?

Tags: united-states, congress, house-of-representatives

In the United States House of Representatives, what happens after a resolution is sent to the house with an unfavorable recommendation - for example, Congressman Nadler's [H.Res 111](https://www.congress.gov/bill/115th-congress/house-resolution/111/actions) - I suspect this resolution will be tabled and die on the floor of the house, but is the House still able to debate on and vote on this resolution if the political winds were to shift? Are there any restrictions placed on it with an unfavorable recommendation?

Comment: What do you mean by an unfavorable recommendation? As far as I know that is not an 'official' parliamentary tool.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be frequently used, but it [does appear to be a formal designation in the House](http://palazzo.house.gov/legislation/how-congress-works.htm). I suspect in this particular case, it was given a recommendation (instead of dying in committee) because an unaddressed [resolution of inquiry](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/GPO-HPRACTICE-104/pdf/GPO-HPRACTICE-104-50.pdf) automatically triggers a full floor debate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Q: Are there any restrictions placed on [a resolution] with an unfavorable recommendation?*

No.

As noted in [H.Res.111](https://www.congress.gov/bill/115th-congress/house-resolution/111),

> 03/08/2017 Placed on the House Calendar, Calendar No. 18.

The [House Calendar](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/CCAL-115hcal-2017-03-09/pdf/CCAL-115hcal-2017-03-09-pt3.pdf) for March 9, 2017 shows H.Res.111 and Judiciary as Number 18.

Under House Rule XIV - Order and Priority of Business,

> 4. After the unfinished business has been disposed of, the Speaker shall call each standing committee in regular order and then select committees. Each committee when named may call up for consideration a bill or resolution reported by it on a previous day and on the House Calendar.

Note that "may call up for consideration" leaves it to the chair (or other authorized member) of the committee to decide whether, and which resolution, to consider. Thus, the resolution could have been "called up" on March 9th or any later date the House was in session during the 115th Congress, provided the Judiciary were called upon.

Note also, in [Resolutions of Inquiry](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/GPO-HPRACTICE-104/pdf/GPO-HPRACTICE-104-50.pdf),

> Who May Call Up
>
> Normally, when a resolution of inquiry has been reported by committee
> within the 14-day time frame (§ 4, supra), only an authorized member of
> that committee may call up the resolution for consideration. 6 Cannon § 413.
> By reporting a resolution of inquiry, even adversely, within 14 legislative
> days, the committee of jurisdiction retains control of the resolution, and a
> Member not authorized by the committee cannot call up the resolution. 8
> Cannon § 2310.

The [final House Calendar](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/CCAL-115hcal-S2/pdf/CCAL-115hcal-S2-pt4.pdf) for the 115th Congress contained 17 resolutions marked "Adverse" (or unfavorable recommendation) of 38 items not called up.